# How to use one module with distinct configurations?

Tags: php, joomla

So I am using the latestnews_modules in joomla, and I am rendering latest_news at the footer of the site, but also I need to render at the right other latest_news, but I see only one view default.php, how can I make that one module works different in each position???

if I create another module like the previous, they bot have the same behavior, how can this be solved, help!!

Answer (score 1):

There should be configurable settings for the module:

1. Go to the module you wish to change
2. Look on the right; you should see a 'panel' headed 'Parameters'
3. You can set things such as the total count, the section/category to pull articles from, authors to include, and the order.

If your requirements are different from that offered by the module, you'll need to either create your own custom extension, or find a third-party extension that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

a) If you want different "behaviour", i.e. different functionality you need two different modules and in that case would need to clone the latestnews module with your modifications. By the way, if you are modifying the code of core modules you really should do this using template overrides in case you end up losing your changes after a security patch - unlikely for this module, but possible.

b) If you want the same behaviour with different parameters do as Bobby Jack says and change the settings for one of the modules by going to the Module Manager, selecting the module and changing it's settings, e.g. how many items to display and from what category.

c) If you want different styling for the two modules use the Module Class Suffix to change the class attribute of one of the modules and write CSS to override the display of the relevant module instance.